# WCF REST service doesn't return anything because I have a circular reference (I think)

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I'm developing a WCF REST service using Entity Framework Code First data layer and I have a navigation property.

**User** class:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string InterestIn { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<User> FromWhomIsFriend { get; set; }
}
```

**ServiceContract** method:

```
public List<User> GetUserFriends(string user_id)
{
    int userId;
    OutgoingWebResponseContext ctx =
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;

    if ((user_id == null) ||
        (!Int32.TryParse(user_id, out userId)) ||
        (userId < 1))
    {
        ctx.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        ctx.StatusDescription = "user_id parameter is not valid";
        throw new ArgumentException("GetUserFriends: user_id parameter is not valid", "user_id");
    }

    List<User> friends = null;

    try
    {
        using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
        {
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            var users = from u in context.Users.Include("Friends")
                        where u.UserId == userId
                        select u;

            if ((users != null) &&
                (users.Count() > 0))
            {
                User user = users.First();
                //friends = user.Friends.ToList();

                friends = new List<User>();
                foreach (User f in user.Friends)
                {
                    User us = new User()
                    {
                        UserId = f.UserId,
                        Name = f.Name,
                        Age = f.Age,
                        City = f.City,
                        Country = f.Country,
                        Email = f.Email,
                        InterestIn = f.InterestIn,
                        Friends = f.Friends,
                        FromWhomIsFriend = f.FromWhomIsFriend
                    };
                    friends.Add(us);
                }
            }

            ctx.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ctx.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        ctx.StatusDescription = ex.Message; 
        ctx.SuppressEntityBody = true;
    }

    return friends;
}
```

This method doesn't return anything. If I comment this line `FromWhomIsFriend = f.FromWhomIsFriend` it works.

`FromWhomIsFriend` is a navigation property to the user from whom I am his friend. To represent user relationship I have this table:

```
UserID   | FriendID
---------+----------
  3      |    1
---------+----------
  1      |    2
```

If I ask about friends from user 1, I get user 2, and its `FromWhomIsFriend` pointing to user 1. And user 1 `Friends` navigation property pointing to user 2, and continues.

**Do you know how why I don't return anything?**

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable proxy creation  in order to support the lazy loading. What you can do is to use `Include` in your query to load the navigation property .

```
        var users = from u in context.Users.Include(u=>u.Friends)
                    where u.UserId == userId
                    select u;
```

Or else the other solution is using separate object model as the WCF contracts(DTO). Then you can enable lazy loading and then copy all the required values form the EF entity object(proxy) to your new Data Transfer Object. You can use something like [Automaper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map the object easily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this part `from u in context.Users.Include(u=>u.Friends)` doesn't work. I get this compile error: `can't convert Lambda expression to type string`. But this one, `from u in context.Users.Include("Friends")` compiles. And finally, it doesn't work because I return PROXY objects, and these objects can't be serialized.

Comment: What version of Ef are you using?

Comment: Disable lazy loading... Lazy loading is not needed when we are using Include to load

Comment: I'm using the latest one. I get it using NGET.

Comment: I've updated my question with your answer but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Add `using System.Data.Entity;`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, but it doesn't work. BTW, I've added it on ServiceContract implementation.

Comment: What do you mean you mean by not working now .. Have you disabled lazy loading?

Comment: I've found where is the error, but I don't know how to solve it. I have updated the question with more information about it.

Comment: I think the is that I have circular references: user1 has user2 as friend, and user2 has user1 as from whom is friend.